# How to create a static route for one interface and keep access for another?

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I have a Debian 9 server with 2 network interfaces: eth0 wired to a 4G router and wlan0 connected to the access point. I need to route outgoing traffic to public IP via wlan0 to transfer files via ssh.

I tried adding the following static route.

```
ip route add <public IP network / 24> via <Wifi gateway> dev wlan0
```

It works because when transferring files I see that the transfer rate of the wlan0 is increasing

The problem is that I need to receive connections from the same public IP for the eth0 interface and after adding the static route I lose the connection. When I try from another IP have access. I receive these connections through the 4G router and they go to the internal IP of the server (eth0).

Doing a tcpdump I see that the connection attempts arrive at the server from the public IP, but since the static route is in wlan0 there is no response. For example if I curl to 80 port I see the attempts but no response from Apache. Is it possible to redirect incoming connections from a specific port to eth0 ignoring the static route?

There is no firewall configured.

My "ip r" when add the new route:

```
default via 10.80.4.1 dev eth0 onlink
10.80.4.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.80.4.2
<public IP network>/24 via 192.168.200.1 dev wlan0 (new route)
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.200.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.18
```

If you need more information, please ask me. Thank you very much.